# Spiral matrix in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, spiral

I have a program where I have to fill a matrix a[n][n] with the numbers from 1 to n in a spiral form. However my program fills only the border of the matrix. My question is how can I optimize the algorithm so that it fills the whole 2d-array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void print();
const int n=9;
int a[n][n];
int main()
{
    int counter=1,j=0,i=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i][j]=counter;
        counter++;
    }
    counter--;
    for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
    {

        a[n-1][k]=counter;
        counter++;
    }
    counter--;
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        a[i][n-1]=counter;
        counter++;
    }
    counter--;
    for(int j=n-1; j>0; j--)
    {
        a[i][j]=counter;
        counter++;
    }
    print();
    return 0;
}

void print ()
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {

            cout<<a[i][j]<<'\t';
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you wrote, you need 4 loops, one for going left, one for going down, one for going right and one for going up again. However, you need to keep track of from where to where you need to go. Eg. The first time you go left, you go from 0 to n-1, the second time only from 1 to n-2, etc. I'm convinced you can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several thing that need to be tweeked:

- You need another loop around what you already have that repeats your circle motion for each round of the spiral and reduces the size of the circle with every iteration (this is the `m` in my example which is reduced towards zero).
- You initialize `int i` and `int j` at the beginning of your main function but in the loops you use `for (int i=0;...)` which means that you are not using the values of previously defined integers.

In the end this looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void print();
const int n=6;
int a[n][n];
int main()
{
    int counter = 1;
    for (int m = n; m > 0; m--)
    {
        int j=n-m,i=0;
        for(i=n-m; i<m; i++)
        {
            a[i][j]=counter;
            counter++;
        }
        counter--;
        for(int k=n-m; k<m; k++)
        {
            a[m-1][k]=counter;
            counter++;
        }
        counter--;
        for(i=m-1; i>=n-m; i--)
        {
            a[i][m-1]=counter;
            counter++;
        }
        counter--;
        for(j=m-1; j>n-m; j--)
        {
            a[n-m][j]=counter;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    print();    
    return 0;
}
```

Using your `print()` this yields:

```
1       20      19      18      17      16                                                                                     
2       21      32      31      30      15                                                                                     
3       22      33      36      29      14                                                                                     
4       23      34      35      28      13                                                                                     
5       24      25      26      27      12                                                                                     
6       7       8       9       10      11
```

Note that I chose `n=6` here.